# Disabling Environmental Variables

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

How could I disable an environmental variable ie. %TIME% from giving an output and would stay as %TIME% when copied into a text file? `echo %TIME% > Example.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I understand the question you want to print simply `%time%`

From batch file:

```
echo %%time%%
```

from command prompt:

```
echo %^time%
```